# Executing sql script in c++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am new to SQL. is it possible with use of some library in c++to execute sql commands like

```
    std::shared_ptr<database> ptr( new odb::sqlite::database ("database.db",      
    SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE));
    //the above line contains the  pointer and the lower line contains the function that executes the query on the databse with the pointer
    executesql("select * from tablea where x> y ", ptr);
```

becasue what is happening with me is that i get sql queries from another machine in the "select from etc..." format and i want to execute it in a similar fashion without going into parsing stuff and writing new code to do so.

Comment: There are many C++ libraries like that.

Comment: Questions to find a library [are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). A question whether some specific library would be fit for some specific requirements would be on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
its given in a lot of detail at the following link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/378808/Accessing-a-SQLite-Database-with-Cplusplus.